# Generate SQL query to return all Items of Users belonging to Groups that also contain CurrentUser

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am have a Postgresql db where Users belong to Groups via Memberships and have Items. I want to return all of the Other Users in the Groups User1 belongs to and then return all the Items that belong to them. I think my basic trouble is that I need the User table twice to get info about current User and then later to get info about the User who owns the Item. I have tried a few queries including:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM groups 
  JOIN memberships ON groups.id = memberships.users_id 
  JOIN users ON memberships.users_id = users.id 
  JOIN books ON users.id = books.users_id;
```

Here is the db schema:

Users:

```
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |        Default              | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------  id         | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |   username   | character varying(255)   |           | not null |         | extended |              |   email      | character varying(255)   |  |          |                                   | extended |            |   password   | character varying(255)   |           |          |     | extended |              |   created_at | timestamp with time zone |  |          |                                   | plain    |            |   updated_at | timestamp with time zone |           |          |     | plain    |              |   avatar_url | character varying(255)   |  |          |                                   | extended |            |   bio        | text                     |           |          |     | extended |              |   location   | character varying(255)   |  |          |                                   | extended |            |   twitter_id | character varying(255)   |           |          |     | extended |              |  Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "users_email_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (email)
    "users_username_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (username) Referenced by:
    TABLE "acts" CONSTRAINT "acts_users_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (users_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "items" CONSTRAINT "items_users_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (users_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "memberships" CONSTRAINT "memberships_users_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (users_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "posts" CONSTRAINT "posts_users_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (users_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Groups:

```
   Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |       Default               | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------  id          | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('groups_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |   name  | character varying(255)   |           | not null |                    | extended |              |   description | text                     | |          |                                    | extended |           |   created_at  | timestamp with time zone |           |          |    | plain    |              |   updated_at  | timestamp with time zone | |          |                                    | plain    |           |  Indexes:
    "groups_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "groups_name_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name) Referenced by:
    TABLE "memberships" CONSTRAINT "memberships_groups_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (groups_id) REFERENCES groups(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "posts" CONSTRAINT "posts_groups_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (groups_id) REFERENCES groups(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Memberships:

```
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |        Default                 | Storage | Stats target | Description 
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------  id         | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('memberships_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              |   users_id   | integer                  |           | not null |         | plain   |              |   groups_id  | integer                  |   | not null |                                         | plain   |       |   created_at | timestamp with time zone |           |          |     | plain   |              |   updated_at | timestamp with time zone |   |          |                                         | plain   |       |  Indexes:
    "memberships_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "memberships_users_id_groups_id_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (users_id, groups_id) Foreign-key constraints:
    "memberships_groups_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (groups_id) REFERENCES groups(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "memberships_users_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (users_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Items:

```
   Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |       Default              | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------  id          | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('items_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |   title  | character varying(255)   |           |          |                    | extended |              |   subtitle    | character varying(255)   | |          |                                   | extended |            |   providers     | text[]                   |           |          |  | extended |              |   description | text                     | |          |                                   | extended |            |   isbn        | character varying(255)   |           |          |    | extended |              |   cover_url   | character varying(255)   | |          |                                   | extended |            |   categories  | text[]                   |           |          |    | extended |              |   users_id    | integer                  | |          |                                   | plain    |            |   created_at  | timestamp with time zone |           |          |    | plain    |              |   updated_at  | timestamp with time zone | |          |                                   | plain    |            |  Indexes:
    "items_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id) Foreign-key constraints:
    "items_users_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (users_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: not sure why I got a downvote here...

Comment: Yup, just join to `users` a second time with a different alias. `users` (current) -> `memberships` -> `groups` -> `users` -> `books`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return 1 row for each of the other users and for each of their items:

```
select un.*, i.*
from users u
inner join memberships m on m.users_id = u.id
inner join memberships mn on mn.groups_id = m.groups_id
inner join users un on un.id = mn.users_id and un.id <> u.id
left join items i on i.users_id = un.id
where u.username = 'User1'
```

and this will return 1 row for each of the other users, with a comma separated list with their items:

```
select un.id, un.username, string_agg(i.id::varchar(20), ',') as itemlist
from users u
inner join memberships m on m.users_id = u.id
inner join memberships mn on mn.groups_id = m.groups_id
inner join users un on un.id = mn.users_id and un.id <> u.id
left join items i on i.users_id = un.id
where u.username = 'User1'
group by un.id, un.username
```

Comment: I don't get the notation. what is memberships mn?

Comment: mn is alias for the 2nd *copy* of the table memberships.

Comment: also this: un.id <> i.id, why do I compare the user id to the item id?

Comment: ok, the first query works, getting this error on the second one: ERROR:  function string_agg(integer, unknown) does not exist

Comment: I guess i.id is integer, right? See my edited answer.

Comment: If, I remove string_agg ... as itemlist and just put i.id and add i.id to th group by clause, i get the table with all users and their item ids, but not aggregated, also, i need to fix one of the joins to be inner, to exclude the users with no items

Comment: I changed the initial query to LEFT join just to include users with no items. If you don't need them then change to INNER. As for the removing string_agg(), why? Don't you want all the items in 1 row?

Comment: the last one was perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201736/discussion-between-user2799827-and-forpas).